# How to start matlab by setting a environment variables?

Tags: matlab

As the title ,every time I start the matlab by shell on linux , I have to type "path/to/matlab/matlab(.sh)"to start it . I had set a SymbolicLink by using the ln command ,but I do not content about it. I wander whether should I set a environment variables to start it ? when I wanna start it, simplely by typing the command such as "matlab".Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You should define your env variable PATH such way, that it contains path to your matlab executable.

How to do this depends on which shell you are using.

Comment: I use bash ,could you tell me how to do it in detail ? thank you, I have find the way for the whole afternoon..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a very annoying problem, because matlab erases the environment variables defined in the shell.

The solution I found is to edit, or create the file ~/.matlab/YOUR_VERSION/mexopts.sh and to define your environnement variable there.

Comment: I recently found that to set the env variables by modifying the /etc/profile by using root.The file can set env variables for the whole system.

Comment: Are you sure that matlab does not erase that to put its standard environnement variable?